# Using -0 with xargs

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I am trying to give an input to xargs that is NUL separated. To this effect I have this:

```
$ echo -n abc$'\000'def$'\000' | xargs -0 -L 1
```

I get

```
abcdef
```

I wonder why doesn't it print o/p as

```
abc
def
```

Comment: I suggest using the `printf` command rather than `echo`.  It's behavior is much more consistent.  `echo` can be an external command, `/bin/echo`, which varies from one system to another, or it's a shell builtin in several different shells, again with different behavior from one system to another.  It's fine for simple `echo hello world` cases, and it's probably ok when your script is intended only to be used with bash, but for anything that as complicated as what you're doing I'd use `printf`.  In your case: `printf 'abc\0def\0'`

Comment: I just realized that `printf` is also a `bash` builtin as well as an external command, but the differences are relatively minor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that you forgot `-e`:

```
$ echo -n abc$'\000'def$'\000' |cat -v
abcdef
```

No zero bytes are seen. But this:

```
$ echo -en abc'\000'def'\000' |cat -v
abc^@def^@
```

is more like it, the `^@` is how `cat -v` shows a zero byte. And now for `xargs`:

```
$ echo -en abc'\000'def'\000' | xargs -0 -L 1
abc
def
```

Try `help echo` from your bash prompt.

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer, yes I forgot -e!

Comment: Not really: you expected $'\000' to produce a literal NUL character in the argument list to `echo` which it didn't. Because of how argument lists are communicated between processes (array of C strings, which are zero-terminated) there is unfortunately no way to have literal NULs in arguments.

Comment: `od -c` is a better way to view control chars

Comment: @glenn: I find `cat -v` easier to read when I'm expecting text with a few control characters mixed in, I'd use `od` or `hexdump` if I was looking at a binary mess with with some text mixed in.

Comment: @tripleee: Not sure what mean. `echo` will interpret the backslashed octal codes (when `-e` is given) and send those to the standard output, no one is trying to put a zero byte into `argv`.

Comment: @mu is too short: huh? Right up there in the question you have `echo -n abc$'\000'def$'\000'` which you would rightfully expect to work (or maybe at least split `abc` and `def` into separate arguments).

Comment: @tripleee: And the question is pretty much "why doesn't `echo -n ...` work?". Or maybe you forget to address your response to abc and we're having pointer dereferencing problems with your "you" in "you expected". Talking about different things tends to lead to confusion.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I was responding to @abc.

Comment: @triplee, I see what you are saying. using $'\000' with echo -e does not work, but '\000' does. So, there is no way to represent NULs in arguments, is what you are saying..right?

Comment: @abc: precisely, you have to use a utility which allows you to represent them symbolically somehow; certainly `echo -e` allows you to do that, but your original attempt with `echo -n` was very good, and failed for what I would call rather esoteric reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try treating the input as a single quoted string.

```
echo -ne "abc\0def\0" | xargs -0 -L 1
```